# No login screen on boot up

Tags: login, login-screen, keyrings

When I boot up my system it goes straight to my desktop without asking for my password on the login page. Instead there is a keyring prompt that comes up where I have to type the password. Any suggestions on how to get the login screen back

Answer (score 0):

Try

- **System Settings > User Accounts > Automatic Login Toogle** - Turn it Off / Disable it
- Reboot System to check

Comment: I've tried that @Back.Slash .It's not working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F2. It will then ask you for your username. Type in your username. It will then ask you for your password. Type in your password. You are using a virtual terminal when you press Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Same thing happens with Ctrl+Alt+F2-6. Ctrl+Alt+F7 brings you back to the GUI.

Try running  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` in the virtual terminal. Then select the option that you aren't using. After that, do `sudo shutdown now -r`. That will restart your PC. It should work now. If it still doesn't work, follow the steps in the 1st paragraph, then go to the 4th paragraph.

After you reboot and are in the virtual terminal again, type `sudo lightdm` or `sudo`  followed by the other option from the sudo dpkg-reconfigure command, then follow the step in the 2nd paragraph. The login screen should be there now.